# alinear tabla al centro con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

queria alinear esta tabla al centro con bootstrap. Utilizo d-block porque si utilizo d-flex me estira la tabla hasta ocupar toda la pagina como se ve mas abajo.

```css
.cuadroLogin
{
    height:550px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-block justify-content-center cuadroLogin" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table border="1">
            <th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Articulo1</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

si uso d-flex me la alinea sin problemas pero la tabla se estira hasta ocupar toda la pantalla.

```css
.cuadroLogin
{
    height:550px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center cuadroLogin" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table border="1">
            <th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Articulo1</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al **div** prueba agregarle `col-auto` o `tex-center`, para alinear al centro verticalmente:

```
<div class="col-auto"> 

 <table class="table table-striped"></table>

</div>

<div class="tex-center"> 
 <table class="table table-striped"></table>
</div>
```